# Extending Ember LinkView

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Ember.LinkView, the the view class behind the handlebars {{linkTo}} helper is now public in Ember 1.0 RC2.  I want to extend it so I can create a custom view without having an extra nested tag for linkTo.

For example:

```
App.MyLinkView = Ember.LinkView.extend({
    namedRoute: 'another'
});
```

then

```
{{#view App.MyLinkView}}LinkView to another route{{/view}}
```

Looked through the source a bit without much luck, as it constantly throws an error.
Here's a jsfiddle with the standard {{linkTo}} working, and the LinkView attempt commented out so it doesn't throw an error.

http://jsfiddle.net/HgmEy/1/

---

**Edit:**

Here is a more realistic example of why you would want to do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/HgmEy/3/

The desired functionality is working here using a regular view, however using a LinkView would be preferred to avoid the extra dom element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkView is intended to be created via a helper, which passes (and provides default values for) some options.

Your error occurs when trying to determine whether your custom class is  `active` or not. You'll need to do one of the following

- pass or supply the expected default options when using your App.MyLinkView
- override the `active` function and implement what you need
- just pass options to `{{linkTo}}` for the behavior you want
- reopen Ember.LinkView to provide the app-wide behavior you'd want

Comment: Thanks Trek, still no luck.  I added a better example.  I'm wondering if this can be achieved using a regular view with tagName: 'a'.  Thing is, I want to leverage the route's serialize method to determine the href.

Comment: Got it working by just using a templateName on the linkTo helper. (http://jsfiddle.net/HgmEy/4/)  Works for this situation, although there would still be a need if you want to add extra functionality to the view class.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this to override `Ember.LinkView`'s call to `transitionTo` in order to come up with a solution for jQuery animations between transitions. It seems to me that there are a couple of viable ways to override LinkView. The second one I succeeded with is Trek's last option, and is simpler. This is method #2:

## Method #2

```
{{#linkTo 'items' this eventName="myEvent"}} Link to {{title}} {{/linkTo}}
```

Now rewrite the app-wide LinkView:

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  // this handler is still called on click, but
  // if we specify eventName in our template,
  // we can call that handler only when we need to,
  // or not at all
  click: function (e) {
    var evtName = this.get('eventName');

    // transitionTo was already invoked by
    // this._invoke() if evtName was `click`
    if (evtName === 'click') return;

    e.preventDefault();

    // do some stuff here

    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    this.trigger.apply(this, [evtName].concat(args));
  }
});
```

---

## Method #1

The first method I came up with was to extend `Ember.LinkView` and create a custom Handlebars helper. The Ember source was really handy here for reading, but I had to override a private method, so I don't think this is really ideal. Here's the implementation. Keep in mind I was trying to control when the View triggered a `transitionTo`:

```
{{#appLinkTo 'items' this}} Link to {{title}} {{/appLinkTo}}
```

Now code it up!

```
App.LinkView = Ember.LinkView.extend({
  // always called after this.invoke(),
  // which calls transitionTo
  click: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  },

  // already bound to the click event by this.init().
  // our click handler above always gets called after this one
  _invoke: function (event) {
    // we need to simulate the old _invoke if we
    // want to override its call to transitionTo
    // 
    // https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L297
    var isSimpleClick = Ember.ViewUtils.isSimpleClick;
    if (!isSimpleClick(event)) { return true; }
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.bubbles === false) { event.stopPropagation(); }
    if (this.get('_isDisabled')) { return false; }

    if (this.get('loading')) {
      Ember.Logger.warn("This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.");
      return false;
    }

    // now we can start messing around
    var routeArgs = this.get('routeArgs');
    // routeArgs seems to have format ['routeName', models for dynamic segments]
    this.set('routeArgs', ['group', routeArgs[1]]);

    // if we use:
    this.get('controller').send('someAction', routeArgs);

    // the controller can do in its `someAction` handler:
    // `this.transitionToRoute.apply(this, routeArgs);`
  }
});

// besides the naming, this is verbatim from the end of:
// https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('app-link-to', function(name) {
    var options = [].slice.call(arguments, -1)[0],
        params = [].slice.call(arguments, 0, -1),
        hash = options.hash;

    hash.disabledBinding = hash.disabledWhen;
    hash.parameters = {
      context: this,
      options: options,
      params: params
    };

    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, App.LinkView, options);
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('appLinkTo', Ember.Handlebars.helpers['app-link-to']);
```

---

## Method #3

If you want the best of both, you could combine both methods and extend `Ember.LinkView`, create a custom Handlebars helper, and use custom event names to signify which actions you want to take. That way, overriding `Ember.LinkView`, and overwriting `_invoke` aren't necessary.

Good luck!