# Ember.js: assign active class to element that matches the current route

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

Using Ember, I'd like to render a non-clickable set of breadcrumb elements.  For example, I'd like to show the user which step they're on as part of a 3 step process.  Something like this:

```
Step 1 | Step 2 | Step 3
```

I'd like the currently active step to have an `active` class on it.  I can accomplish this by doing something like this:

```
{{#link-to "step1" tagName="div"}}Step 1{{/link-to}}
```

The problem with this approach though, is that `Step 1` becomes clickable (i.e. clicking on it causes a transition to route) and I don't want it to be clickable. Any way to achieve this using Ember's built-in mechanisms?

Comment: You might be able to add a click event (from the view) to those links and then `event.preventDefault()` or some combination of that family of interrupter methods. I haven't tried overriding ember link-to tags before...

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte. that's an interesting approach, but it seems very hacky.

Comment: For sure, I agree, it's hacky. Any approach will be hacky, though, as you are disabling the core behavior of the `{{#link-to}}` helper.  :) You could also extend or reopen the link-to helper class and create your own component that doesn't transition. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19330151/614152

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBlancarte. I'll have a look at extending link-to, but it still fundamentally seems wrong to extend it for my purpose.  I'm looking for something like {{#if isCurrentRoute}} or <div {{bind-attr class="isCurrentRoute:active"}}></div>.  I can try to build this myself if I knew how link-to is setting the active class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are asking about Ember mechanism, but I don't see a point to do this in javascript, if you can do this so easy in css:

```
.step.active {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: I may not have posed the question very well.  With simply a CSS approach, I'd still have to manually set the active class on the element.  It's the setting of the active class that I'm looking for a solution to.

Comment: But Ember sets the active class automatically on active {{#link-to}} helpers, isn't it?